# How can I fix Django SQLite3 error on AWS?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, sqlite, yum

I am trying to run a django project on an EC2 server, however, when I run `python3 manage.py runserver`, it returns this error, `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.9.0 or later is required (found 3.7.17).`. I then check to see what version of SQLite3 is running on my python installation on my EC2 server by running `sqlite3.sqlite_version`, and it returns 3.7.17. So I then try to update SQLite3 using the default AWS EC2 Amazon Linux package manager, yum, by running `yum install sqlite`. It then returns this, `Package sqlite-3.7.17-8.amzn2.1.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version`, even though it is not the latest version. How can I install the latest version of SQLite3 to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Since my app is very small with little dependency, I was able to quickly switch to EC2 sever running Ubuntu. It is necessary to learn how to use Ubuntu (apt).

You can find right now in the installation:

Package: sqlite3
Version: 3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2